# AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapterConfigurer has been replaced by RequestMappingHandlerAdapter how can use?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i have

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.util.PathMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebBindingInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ModelAndViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MethodNameResolver;
import org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper;


public class AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapterConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter adapter;

    private WebBindingInitializer webBindingInitializer;

    private HttpMessageConverter[] messageConverters;
    private PathMatcher pathMatcher;
    private UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper;
    private MethodNameResolver methodNameResolver;
    private WebArgumentResolver[] customArgumentResolvers;
    private ModelAndViewResolver[] customModelAndViewResolvers;

    private boolean replaceMessageConverters = false;

    public void init() {
        if (webBindingInitializer != null) {
            adapter.setWebBindingInitializer(webBindingInitializer);
        }

        if (messageConverters != null) {
            if (replaceMessageConverters) {
                adapter.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
            } else {
                adapter.setMessageConverters(mergeMessageConverters());
            }
        }

        if (pathMatcher != null) {
            adapter.setPathMatcher(pathMatcher);
        }

        if (urlPathHelper != null) {
            adapter.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
        }

        if (methodNameResolver != null) {
            adapter.setMethodNameResolver(methodNameResolver);
        }

        if (customArgumentResolvers != null) {
            adapter.setCustomArgumentResolvers(customArgumentResolvers);
        }

        if (customModelAndViewResolvers != null) {
            adapter.setCustomModelAndViewResolvers(customModelAndViewResolvers);
        }
    }

    private HttpMessageConverter[] mergeMessageConverters() {
        return (HttpMessageConverter[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(messageConverters, adapter.getMessageConverters());
    }

    public void setWebBindingInitializer(WebBindingInitializer webBindingInitializer) {
        this.webBindingInitializer = webBindingInitializer;
    }

    public void setPathMatcher(PathMatcher pathMatcher) {
        this.pathMatcher = pathMatcher;
    }

    public void setUrlPathHelper(UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper) {
        this.urlPathHelper = urlPathHelper;
    }

    public void setMethodNameResolver(MethodNameResolver methodNameResolver) {
        this.methodNameResolver = methodNameResolver;
    }

    public void setCustomArgumentResolver(WebArgumentResolver argumentResolver) {
        this.customArgumentResolvers = new WebArgumentResolver[] { argumentResolver };
    }

    public void setCustomArgumentResolvers(WebArgumentResolver[] argumentResolvers) {
        this.customArgumentResolvers = argumentResolvers;
    }

    public void setCustomModelAndViewResolver(ModelAndViewResolver customModelAndViewResolver) {
        this.customModelAndViewResolvers = new ModelAndViewResolver[] { customModelAndViewResolver };
    }

    public void setCustomModelAndViewResolvers(ModelAndViewResolver[] customModelAndViewResolvers) {
        this.customModelAndViewResolvers = customModelAndViewResolvers;
    }

    public void setMessageConverters(HttpMessageConverter[] messageConverters) {
        this.messageConverters = messageConverters;
    }

    public void setReplaceMessageConverters(boolean replaceMessageConverters) {
        this.replaceMessageConverters = replaceMessageConverters;
    }
}
```

but now with Spring 3.1 `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` has been replaced by `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, how can change my class `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapterConfigurer` for Spring 3.1? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Spring 3.1 you need to use [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) to customize the spring mvc configuration